# pathForResource inDirectory problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i want to load html file from Resources in WebView.

in Resources i have:

test.html

testfolder->test.html

this code works perfectly:

```
[[webview1 mainFrame] loadRequest:
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]]]];
```

and this one - crash the app (SIGABRT):

```
[[webview1 mainFrame] loadRequest:
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"  inDirectory:@"testfolder" ]]]];
```

How can i get files from folders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going about it the right way, so that means either you've got a typo in your file/directory name or the "testfolder" directory isn't getting included in your application bundle.

Make sure that "testfolder"  is in the Resources section of your XCode project as a folder (not a group).

Look at the "Build Results" window when you build your application; you should see steps in there that say "copy test.html" and "copy testfolder".

Note that (when building for the simulator) you can also examine the contents of the application bundle directly -- look in Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications

Comment: thanks! that help.
and hint - the group show in resources with yellow folder icon, the folders with blue folder icon.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for NSURL fileURLWithPath: says

> **Parameters**
>
> path
>
> The path that the NSURL object will represent. path should be a valid
>   system path. If path begins with a
>   tilde, it must first be expanded with
>   stringByExpandingTildeInPath.
>
> **Passing nil for this parameter produces an exception.**

and for NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:

> **Return Value**
>
> The full pathname for the resource
>   file or **nil if the file could not be
>   located.**

Could it be that the file is not in the directory path that you specify?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a "Group" in XCode doesn't create a real Directory within your app Bundle.

You need to import the directory into your app using the following method in your project "Test":

1. File -> Select "Add Files To Test"
2. Select the Directory you want to import
3. In the pop-up window make sure you select "Copy items into destination group's folder" and "Create Folder References for any added folders"

Hit "Add"

Your done!

The Directory should appear blue instead of yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.
Are you sure your folder *testfolder* is included in your build?

If not, your call to pathForResource: ofType: inDirectory: will return nil.
And according to the [documentation of the NSURL class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:), passing nil for the parameter of the fileURLWithPath: class method produces an exception.

To check that your folder is included in your build process, expand the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase, and look for your folder. If it is not there, drag and drop it into it.

A way to check that you added it correctly is to navigate to your builded application, right click on it and select the  "Show Package Contents" item.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to load from a directory, you first gotta add the directory to the project with the create directory references (so that in Copy Bundle Resources you get a blue icon with the main folder name and **not individual files**!)
2. Don't use the in directory parameter at all. Just use the global path with slashes ("/") instead of backslashes ("\") like in Windows.